# Django DeleteView strange behavior

Tags: python, django, reverse, django-urls, django-class-based-views

So I have a problem with a Django class-based Delete View. Actually, the delete view works just fine as it deletes the chosen entry, but the problem occurs when I want to redirect to the DetailView URL of the page where all entries are.

```
class DeleteStavkeView(DeleteView):
    model = Stavke
    template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/stavke_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        rn_id = self.object.Rn_id
        cijena_stavke_del = self.object.Cijena

        ### UZIMANJE TRENUTNE CIJENE NA TOM RADNOM NALOG ###
        trenutna_cijena = Radni_nalozi.objects.values_list('Cijena').filter(id=rn_id)
        trenutna_cijena = trenutna_cijena[0][0]

        ### UMANJUJEMO TRENUTNU CIJENU ZA CIJENU STAVKE KOJU BRIŠEMO
        nova_cijena_rn = trenutna_cijena - cijena_stavke_del

        ### POSTAVLJAMO NOVU CIJENU
        rn_cijena = Radni_nalozi.objects.get(id=rn_id)
        rn_cijena.Cijena = nova_cijena_rn
        rn_cijena.save()

        ### REDIRECTAMO VIEW
        return reverse_lazy('detalji_rn', kwargs={'pk': rn_id})
```

As you can see in the code above, I am using reverse lazy with a pk of the page before. But after I confirm to delete it seems like Django is trying to get to the same delete URL once again and I am always getting the same error that URL is not found.

[Django Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ0xH.png)

It seems like it's trying to get to the URL of the entry that was just deleted so obviously there is none found. I can't understand what am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
    path('radni_nalozi/details_rn/<pk>', views.RadniDetailView.as_view(), name="detalji_rn"),
    path('radni_nalozi/update/<pk>', views.RadniUpdateView.as_view(), name="update_rn"),
    path('radni_nalozi/delete/<pk>', views.RadniDeleteView.as_view(), name="delete_rn"),

    path('radni_nalozi/add_stavke/<pk>', views.AddStavkeView.as_view(), name="add_stavke_rn"),
    path('radni_nalozi/delete_stavke/<pk>', views.DeleteStavkeView.as_view(), name="delete_item"),
```

**EDIT [7.4.22.]**

To make it clear. I have a list view of all the work orders. When I pick one of the work orders I go to the detail view of that work order. Every work order contains various items attached to him by a foreign key (items that need to be done on that work order). The problem occurs when I delete one of the items on that work order. I want to go back to the detail page of that work order not the list view of all the work orders. So what I want to do is to get a pk of that work order and go back to the refreshed detail page of that work order after I delete one of the items attached to him.

Here you can see my full views.py

```
class Radni_nalozi_view(ListView):
    model = Radni_nalozi
    template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/radni.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Radni_nalozi.objects.filter(Aktivan=1)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'RADNI NALOZI'
        context['link'] = 'dodaj_rn'
        return context


############################# DETAIL VIEW ###########################################
class RadniDetailView(DetailView):
    # specify the model to use
    model = Radni_nalozi
    template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/detalji_rn.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RadniDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        radni_obj = self.object  # this contain the object that the view is operating upon
        context['object'] = radni_obj # don't forget this also

        # Get all items/Stavke related to the work order/Radni_nalozi
        context['items'] = Stavke.objects.filter(Rn=radni_obj)
        context['entries'] = Unosi.objects.filter(Rn=radni_obj)
        context['phases'] = Unosi_faza.objects.filter(Rn=radni_obj)
        return context
    
 
class AddStavkeView(BSModalCreateView):
        model = Stavke
        template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/dodaj_rn.html'
        form_class = StavkeForm
    
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(BSModalCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['title'] = 'DODAVANJE STAVKI NA RADNI NALOG'
            context['gumb'] = 'DODAJ'
    
            ### POVLAČENJE TRENUTNE CIJENE PREMA DODANIM STAVKAMA ###
            rn_cijena = Stavke.objects.values_list('Cijena').filter(Rn_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
            global cijena
            cijena = 0
            for i in range(len(rn_cijena)):
                cijena = cijena + (rn_cijena[i][0])
    
            return context
    
    
        # DODAJ NOVE STAVKE I STAVI DA JE RN_ID JEDNAK PRIMARNOM KLJUČU
        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.Rn_id = self.kwargs['pk']
    
            ### POVLAČENJE UPISANIH KOMADA I ODABRANOG ARTIKLA SA FORME
            kom = form.cleaned_data['Komada']
            get_artikl = form.cleaned_data['Artikl']
    
            ### POVLAČENJE TRENUTNIH CIJENA ARTIKALA I DODAVANJE NA STAVKE (pridodavanje aktualnih cijena radnom nalogu)
            get_artikl = str(get_artikl).split(", ")
            print(get_artikl)
            artikl_cijena = Artikli.objects.values_list('Cijena').filter(Artikl=get_artikl[1])
            artikl_cijena = artikl_cijena[0][0]
            print(artikl_cijena)
            ### RAČUNANJE CIJENA PREMA BROJU KOMADA I AKTUALNIM CIJENAMA ARTIKALA I SPREMANJE U BAZU
            stavka_cijena = artikl_cijena * kom
            form.instance.Cijena = stavka_cijena
    
            nova_cijena_rn = stavka_cijena + cijena
    
            rn_cijena = Radni_nalozi.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
            rn_cijena.Cijena = nova_cijena_rn
            rn_cijena.save()
    
            return super(AddStavkeView, self).form_valid(form)
    
    
        def get_success_url(self):
              ### NAKON USPJEŠNOG SUBMITANJA REDIRECTAJ NA NEKI DRUGI URL
              rn_id=self.kwargs['pk']
              return reverse_lazy('detalji_rn', kwargs={'pk': rn_id})
    
    
    


class DeleteStavkeView(DeleteView):
            model = Stavke
            template_name = 'app/radni_nalozi/stavke_delete.html'
        
            def get_success_url(self):
                ### UZIMANJE ID-a radnog naloga i CIJENE STAVKE KOJU BRIŠEMO SA TOG RN-a
                rn_id = self.object.Rn_id
                cijena_stavke_del = self.object.Cijena
        
                ### UZIMANJE TRENUTNE CIJENE NA TOM RADNOM NALOG ###
                trenutna_cijena = Radni_nalozi.objects.values_list('Cijena').filter(id=rn_id)
                trenutna_cijena = trenutna_cijena[0][0]
        
                ### UMANJUJEMO TRENUTNU CIJENU ZA CIJENU STAVKE KOJU BRIŠEMO
                nova_cijena_rn = trenutna_cijena - cijena_stavke_del
        
                ### POSTAVLJAMO NOVU CIJENU
                rn_cijena = Radni_nalozi.objects.get(id=rn_id)
                rn_cijena.Cijena = nova_cijena_rn
                rn_cijena.save()
        
                ### REDIRECTAMO VIEW
                return reverse_lazy('detalji_rn', kwargs={'pk': rn_id})
```

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Put the code itself in your question.

Comment: In the code you have shown us, there is no list view. There is only a detail view which shows a single object - and you're trying to show the detail view for the object you have just deleted, which is why it fails.

Comment: create a ```listview``` and add it as your ```success_url``` in your ```delete``` view